# Update manager: "A problem occurred when checking for the updates"

Tags: software-center, update-manager

As of a few days ago I have this red circle with a horizontal white line through it persist on the panel in the top right.  When I mouse over it, it says "A problem occurred when checking for the updates".

When there are updates to install, I can double click it and hit the 'install updates' button. There is a brief progress bar, and then nothing happens. I can right click the red circle and click 'insall all updates', and then it says its "marking" the updates à la synaptic package manager, and subsequently installs them.

The circle won't go away and it's just annoying. I'm not sure how it would be related, but since this started, I havn't been able to open ubuntu software centre. When I go applications> ubuntu software centre, my cursor just turns into the loading one for a few seconds, then nothing happens.

Any help is very appreciated.

Update: contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` (without comments):

```
?deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted

deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted

deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe

deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wgrant/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wgrant/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
```

Update: contents of /var/log/apt/history.log:

```
Start-Date: 2010-11-01  11:15:47
Commandline: apt-get install gparted
Install: gparted:amd64 (0.6.2-1ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2010-11-01  11:16:04

Start-Date: 2010-11-01  23:46:57
Install: realpath:amd64 (1.15build1, automatic), clisp:amd64 (2.48-1.2), libffcall1:amd64 (1.10+cvs20100619-2, automatic), libsigsegv0:amd64 (2.5-3, automatic), libdb4.7:amd64 (4.7.25-9, automatic), common-lisp-controller:amd64 (7.2, automatic), cl-asdf:amd64 (1.704-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2010-11-01  23:47:18

Start-Date: 2010-11-01  23:47:53
Install: gambc:amd64 (4.2.8-1.1), libgambc4:amd64 (4.2.8-1.1, automatic), libgambc4-dev:amd64 (4.2.8-1.1, automatic), gambc-doc:amd64 (4.2.8-1.1, automatic)
End-Date: 2010-11-01  23:48:02

Start-Date: 2010-11-03  12:14:21
Upgrade: chromium-browser:amd64 (6.0.472.63~r59945-0ubuntu2, 7.0.517.41~r62167-0ubuntu0.10.10.1), gwibber-service:amd64 (2.32.0.1-0ubuntu1, 2.32.0.2-0ubuntu1), chromium-browser-inspector:amd64 (6.0.472.63~r59945-0ubuntu2, 7.0.517.41~r62167-0ubuntu0.10.10.1)
End-Date: 2010-11-03  12:14:38

Start-Date: 2010-11-04  11:18:21
Commandline: apt-get install flex
Install: m4:amd64 (1.4.14-3, automatic), flex:amd64 (2.5.35-9.1)
End-Date: 2010-11-04  11:18:29

Start-Date: 2010-11-04  11:18:39
Commandline: apt-get install bison
Install: bison:amd64 (2.4.1.dfsg-3)
End-Date: 2010-11-04  11:18:43

Start-Date: 2010-11-05  10:07:42
Upgrade: libpurple0:amd64 (2.7.3-1ubuntu3, 2.7.3-1ubuntu3.1), libcupsppdc1:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2), libpurple-bin:amd64 (2.7.3-1ubuntu3, 2.7.3-1ubuntu3.1), libcupsimage2:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2), gvfs-fuse:amd64 (1.6.4-0ubuntu1, 1.6.4-0ubuntu1.1), libcupscgi1:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2), libcupsdriver1:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2), ubufox:amd64 (0.9~rc2-0ubuntu5, 0.9~rc2-0ubuntu5.1), gvfs-backends:amd64 (1.6.4-0ubuntu1, 1.6.4-0ubuntu1.1), libasound2-dev:amd64 (1.0.23-1ubuntu2, 1.0.23-1ubuntu2.1), cups-client:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2), libfreetype6:amd64 (2.4.2-2, 2.4.2-2ubuntu0.1), cups-ppdc:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2), lib32asound2:amd64 (1.0.23-1ubuntu2, 1.0.23-1ubuntu2.1), simple-scan:amd64 (2.32.0-0ubuntu3, 2.32.0-0ubuntu4), python-aptdaemon:amd64 (0.31+bzr506-0ubuntu2, 0.31+bzr506-0ubuntu4), cups-common:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2), libcups2:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2), alsa-utils:amd64 (1.0.23-2ubuntu3, 1.0.23-2ubuntu3.4), aptdaemon:amd64 (0.31+bzr506-0ubuntu2, 0.31+bzr506-0ubuntu4), cups:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2), libasound2:amd64 (1.0.23-1ubuntu2, 1.0.23-1ubuntu2.1), flashplugin-installer:amd64 (10.1.85.3ubuntu1, 10.1.102.64ubuntu0.10.10.1), python-aptdaemon-gtk:amd64 (0.31+bzr506-0ubuntu2, 0.31+bzr506-0ubuntu4), libfreetype6-dev:amd64 (2.4.2-2, 2.4.2-2ubuntu0.1), xul-ext-ubufox:amd64 (0.9~rc2-0ubuntu5, 0.9~rc2-0ubuntu5.1), cups-bsd:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2), libgvfscommon0:amd64 (1.6.4-0ubuntu1, 1.6.4-0ubuntu1.1), gvfs:amd64 (1.6.4-0ubuntu1, 1.6.4-0ubuntu1.1), libcupsmime1:amd64 (1.4.4-6ubuntu2.1, 1.4.4-6ubuntu2.2)
End-Date: 2010-11-05  10:08:58

Start-Date: 2010-11-05  20:55:33
Commandline: apt-get install rdiff-backup
Install: python-pylibacl:amd64 (0.5.0-2, automatic), rdiff-backup:amd64 (1.2.8-5ubuntu2), librsync1:amd64 (0.9.7-7, automatic), python-pyxattr:amd64 (0.5.0-2, automatic)
End-Date: 2010-11-05  20:55:47

Start-Date: 2010-11-06  13:17:32
Remove: libswscale0:amd64 (0.6-2ubuntu6), libavutil50:amd64 (0.6-2ubuntu6), gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3:amd64 (0.10.14.debian-1), libboost-date-time1.42.0:amd64 (1.42.0-3ubuntu1), libavcodec52:amd64 (0.6-2ubuntu6), gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:amd64 (0.10.11-1), gnash-common:amd64 (0.8.8-5ubuntu1), libgtkglext1:amd64 (1.2.0-1.1fakesync2), libboost-thread1.42.0:amd64 (1.42.0-3ubuntu1), libpostproc51:amd64 (0.6-2ubuntu6), libavformat52:amd64 (0.6-2ubuntu6), gnash:amd64 (0.8.8-5ubuntu1), libva1:amd64 (1.0.1-3), liboil0.3:amd64 (0.3.16-1ubuntu2)
End-Date: 2010-11-06  13:17:49

Start-Date: 2010-11-06  13:20:00
Remove: lib32bz2-1.0:amd64 (1.0.5-4ubuntu1), lib32ncurses5:amd64 (5.7+20100626-0ubuntu1), nspluginwrapper:amd64 (1.2.2-0ubuntu7), ia32-libs:amd64 (20090808ubuntu9), libc6-i386:amd64 (2.12.1-0ubuntu8), lib32gcc1:amd64 (4.5.1-7ubuntu2), lib32asound2:amd64 (1.0.23-1ubuntu2.1), flashplugin-installer:amd64 (10.1.102.64ubuntu0.10.10.1), lib32z1:amd64 (1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu1), lib32stdc++6:amd64 (4.5.1-7ubuntu2), lib32v4l-0:amd64 (0.6.4-1ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2010-11-06  13:20:09

Start-Date: 2010-11-08  15:46:39
Install: libswscale0:amd64 (0.6-2ubuntu6, automatic), libavutil50:amd64 (0.6-2ubuntu6, automatic), libavcodec52:amd64 (0.6-2ubuntu6, automatic), gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:amd64 (0.10.11-1), libpostproc51:amd64 (0.6-2ubuntu6, automatic), libavformat52:amd64 (0.6-2ubuntu6, automatic), libva1:amd64 (1.0.1-3, automatic)
End-Date: 2010-11-08  15:46:52

Start-Date: 2010-11-09  16:23:09
Install: ubuntuone-client-gnome:amd64 (1.4.4.1-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2010-11-09  16:23:19

Start-Date: 2010-11-09  20:38:53
Install: python2.7:amd64 (2.7-6), python2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7-6, automatic)
End-Date: 2010-11-09  20:39:03

Start-Date: 2010-11-10  09:26:09
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic --dist-upgrade-mode --non-interactive --hide-main-window -o Synaptic::AskRelated=true
Upgrade: python-cupshelpers:amd64 (1.2.3+20100723-0ubuntu8, 1.2.3+20100723-0ubuntu8.1), sysvinit-utils:amd64 (2.87dsf-4ubuntu18, 2.87dsf-4ubuntu19), libsane-hpaio:amd64 (3.10.6-1ubuntu10, 3.10.6-1ubuntu10.1), system-config-printer-gnome:amd64 (1.2.3+20100723-0ubuntu8, 1.2.3+20100723-0ubuntu8.1), hplip-cups:amd64 (3.10.6-1ubuntu10, 3.10.6-1ubuntu10.1), hpijs:amd64 (3.10.6-1ubuntu10, 3.10.6-1ubuntu10.1), hplip:amd64 (3.10.6-1ubuntu10, 3.10.6-1ubuntu10.1), libhpmud0:amd64 (3.10.6-1ubuntu10, 3.10.6-1ubuntu10.1), gdb:amd64 (7.2-1ubuntu2, 7.2-1ubuntu3), system-config-printer-udev:amd64 (1.2.3+20100723-0ubuntu8, 1.2.3+20100723-0ubuntu8.1), system-config-printer-common:amd64 (1.2.3+20100723-0ubuntu8, 1.2.3+20100723-0ubuntu8.1), sysv-rc:amd64 (2.87dsf-4ubuntu18, 2.87dsf-4ubuntu19), initscripts:amd64 (2.87dsf-4ubuntu18, 2.87dsf-4ubuntu19), hplip-data:amd64 (3.10.6-1ubuntu10, 3.10.6-1ubuntu10.1)
End-Date: 2010-11-10  09:26:52

Start-Date: 2010-11-10  18:39:25
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic --dist-upgrade-mode --non-interactive --hide-main-window -o Synaptic::AskRelated=true
Upgrade: chromium-browser:amd64 (7.0.517.41~r62167-0ubuntu0.10.10.1, 7.0.517.44~r64615-0ubuntu0.10.10.1), chromium-browser-inspector:amd64 (7.0.517.41~r62167-0ubuntu0.10.10.1, 7.0.517.44~r64615-0ubuntu0.10.10.1)
End-Date: 2010-11-10  18:39:42

Start-Date: 2010-11-12  19:20:00
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic --dist-upgrade-mode --non-interactive --hide-main-window -o Synaptic::AskRelated=true
Upgrade: libxml2-utils:amd64 (2.7.7.dfsg-4, 2.7.7.dfsg-4ubuntu0.1), xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 (2.12.0-1ubuntu5, 2.12.0-1ubuntu5.1), libvpx0:amd64 (0.9.2-1build1, 0.9.2-1ubuntu0.1), libxml2:amd64 (2.7.7.dfsg-4, 2.7.7.dfsg-4ubuntu0.1), python-libxml2:amd64 (2.7.7.dfsg-4, 2.7.7.dfsg-4ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2010-11-12  19:20:14

Start-Date: 2010-11-13  13:22:38
Commandline: apt-get install ssmtp
Install: ssmtp:amd64 (2.64-4fakesync1)
End-Date: 2010-11-13  13:22:45

Start-Date: 2010-11-13  13:40:07
Commandline: apt-get install mutt
Install: mutt:amd64 (1.5.20-9ubuntu2)
End-Date: 2010-11-13  13:40:13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not using maverick's normal system Python (since the CommandNotFound module has apparently gone missing). Have you installed Python from source? If so, try `sudo ln -sf python2.6 /usr/bin/python`, and `sudo apt-get update` again.

Answer (score 6):

Just run this, it'll solve the problem

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3-minimal
```

Comment: Could you expand on why this solution is better than the accepted answer?

Comment: The accepted answer updates the whole python package, but it can be simplified by only reinstalling the python-minimal / python3-minimal as I proposed.

Answer (score 3):

Opening a terminal and `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin` then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` should solve the issue.

Comment: I did that and restarted, but the problem persists :(

Comment: Have you added any repositories or PPAs to your sources.list? Can you please post the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Done, I added it to the OP because it wouldn't fit in the comments box. Yes, I added someone's launchpad PPA a while back.

Comment: OK, well, you sources.list looks kosher, basically. The only thing that looks suspect (but doesn't actually look suspect really) is the launchpad ppa. Why don't you go ahead and comment it out and apt-update/upgrade while I look around and try to figure out what is going on (just in case that's the issue, but if you don't feel comfortable doing that, then just sit tight and I'll try to see what the problem is in any case).

Comment: I commented out those two lines, and did the apt-update and upgrade, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Ok. Well, I am sorry to report that I've searched as far as I am able and, based on the information you've provided, haven't found a solution. Is there anything else about your system configuration you've left out? What Ubuntu release are you using? Is it an upgrade or a clean install? Etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your attempts. I can't think of anything particularly noteworthy. I'm using 10.10 (the 64bit version), and it's a clean install.

Comment: Last attempt, please post `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log`

Comment: I just added /var/log/apt/history.log. /var/log/apt/term.log is really big, should I still post it?

Comment: If you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` on the command line after removing those cache files, do you get any error messages? If so, are you getting them during the update or when it tries to upgrade?

Comment: Yes, and I believe it's during the update:

Hit http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse amd64 Packages     
Fetched 65B in 6s (9B/s)                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 10, in <module>
   import CommandNotFound
ImportError: No module named CommandNotFound

Comment: you would also want to actually remove the notification in the notifications bar: `killall update-notifier`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-a-171107/