# "a problem occurred when checking for updates" error

Tags: 11.04, update-manager

I've already tried doing what was listed here: [Update manager: "A problem occurred when checking for the updates"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12950/update-manager-a-problem-occurred-when-checking-for-the-updates) but it didnt work.

Every time I click on the red circle with the line through it the update manager pops up and then goes away.

When I try to do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

here's the output:

```
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb InRelease                           
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty InRelease                               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty InRelease                               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates InRelease                       
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty InRelease                                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com natty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security InRelease                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                   
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org natty InRelease                              
Hit http://deb.torproject.org natty InRelease                                  
Get:4 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Get:5 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,214 B]                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty Release.gpg                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security Release.gpg                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb Release.gpg                         
Ign http://deb.paissad.net unstable InRelease                                  
Get:6 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [765 B]                   
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty Release                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates Release.gpg                     
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security Release                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com natty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://deb.paissad.net unstable Release.gpg                                
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org natty/free i386 Packages                     
Hit http://deb.torproject.org natty/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb Release                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release                                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner i386 Packages                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Sources               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources                               
Hit http://deb.paissad.net unstable Release                                    
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner TranslationIndex                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates Release                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main i386 Packages                          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Sources                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Sources               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Sources                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main i386 Packages               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Sources                         
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb/games i386 Packages                 
Hit http://deb.paissad.net unstable/main Sources                               
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org natty/non-free i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Sources                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Sources                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Sources                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main i386 Packages                      
Hit http://deb.torproject.org natty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe i386 Packages           
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main TranslationIndex            
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse TranslationIndex      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted TranslationIndex      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe TranslationIndex        
Hit http://deb.paissad.net unstable/contrib Sources                            
Hit http://deb.paissad.net unstable/non-free Sources                           
Hit http://deb.paissad.net unstable/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://deb.paissad.net unstable/contrib i386 Packages                      
Hit http://deb.paissad.net unstable/non-free i386 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted i386 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse i386 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe i386 Packages                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex                   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse TranslationIndex             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted TranslationIndex             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe TranslationIndex               
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb/games TranslationIndex              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main i386 Packages                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main i386 Packages                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main i386 Packages                          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://deb.paissad.net unstable/contrib TranslationIndex                   
Ign http://deb.paissad.net unstable/main TranslationIndex                      
Ign http://deb.paissad.net unstable/non-free TranslationIndex                  
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org natty/free TranslationIndex                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Sources              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Sources                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Sources                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe i386 Packages          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main i386 Packages                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main i386 Packages                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex                       
Ign http://deb.torproject.org natty/main TranslationIndex                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main TranslationIndex           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted TranslationIndex     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe TranslationIndex       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main i386 Packages                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex                       
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org natty/non-free TranslationIndex              
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner Translation-en_US               
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner Translation-en                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Translation-en_US           
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Translation-en              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Translation-en        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Translation-en_US     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en_US                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Translation-en        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-en_US       
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-en          
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Translation-en_US            
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Translation-en               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Translation-en_US            
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Translation-en               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Translation-en_US              
Ign http://deb.paissad.net unstable/contrib Translation-en_US                  
Ign http://deb.paissad.net unstable/contrib Translation-en                     
Ign http://deb.paissad.net unstable/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://deb.paissad.net unstable/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://deb.paissad.net unstable/non-free Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Translation-en                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Translation-en             
Ign http://deb.paissad.net unstable/non-free Translation-en                    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Translation-en       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Translation-en       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Translation-en_US      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Translation-en         
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb/games Translation-en_US             
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb/games Translation-en                
Ign http://deb.torproject.org natty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://deb.torproject.org natty/main Translation-en
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org natty/free Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org natty/free Translation-en                    
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org natty/non-free Translation-en_US             
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org natty/non-free Translation-en                
Fetched 5,069 B in 9s (544 B/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
alex@griever:~$ ncy tree... 50%
```

and stops there.... doesnt move past that..

anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was `apt-get clean` :) Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Testing on my own PC, using **two** separate commands ..

**STEP 1:**

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://##.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Ign http://##.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates InRelease                     
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric InRelease                             
  :
     (removed for clarity)
  :
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-##_##
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-##
Reading package lists... Done
```

***You have reached here.***

**STEP 2:**

```
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So, you are aborting at 50% of building.

Try this: (attempt to correct broken dependencies)

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same thing, it didn't change, I'm not purposely aborting.  as soon as it reaches 50% it does this: `Reading package lists... Done
alex@griever:~$ ncy tree... 50%` and cuts off the dependency tree word and stays at 50

Comment: Did you try the **update -f** or **upgrade -f** commands?

Comment: I clicked update and it gave me the following: `The package system is broken

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f`

Comment: Add output (to your question) for **cat /etc/apt/sources.list**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it ran `sudo apt-get update` OK but then skipped the `sudo apt-get upgrade` part. Try running `sudo apt-get upgrade` again, post any exact errors you may get.

Comment: here's what I got: 

`Reading package lists... Done
alex@griever:~$ ncy tree... 50%`

and it doesn't go past that

Answer (score 0):

Please check the solution of the linked question,

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3-minimal
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the OP?