# How to install again Update Manager after uninstalling it

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-installation, update-manager

I tried asking many times on few Ubuntu forums how to deal with my non-responsive Update Manager, but all I was getting was the same stuff (run it from the terminal, run some lines, apt-get update blah blah). Nothing was helping. Eventually I went mad Windows style and tried to simply uninstall it and install it again. The problem is - how to install it again? Can't do it through Software Center, can't really build a package (because I'm too stupid to do that). And I seriously want to avoid reinstalling the whole system.

I am running a 12.04 version (Update Manager was unable to update to a newer one)

Comment: How did you uninstall it?

Comment: Also, what happens when you open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and type in `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: *how* (what commands did you use???) did you uninstall it through the terminal???

Answer (score 5):

Terminal/Konsole:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager synaptic
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall update-manager synaptic
```

Comment: what does the commands do in detail? Why do you have two commands?

Comment: `sudo` means "superuser do", requiring administrative rights and password to change the system.  `apt-get` is how Debian-based Linux downloads and installs software from online repositories. `install` means what it says, as does `reinstall`. `update-manager` and `synaptic` are packages `apt-get` is being told to fetch and install.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with update manager so I uninstalled update-manager and installed again by using:

For uninstall

```
sudo apt-get purge update-manager
```

For install

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager synaptic
```

And just worked

Sorry for my spelling

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with a package and you choose to completely re-install it, you should first completely remove it.

```
 sudo apt-get --purge remove update-manager
```

will remove the update manager **and any configuration files it's created.** If there is a configuration error, this will allow you to re-install fron scratch.

Of course, you'll lose all the configuration files, and I'm not sure what this might do. I don't know if those configuration files detail everything installed on your system, and whether you might end up with a butt-load of hurt when your next install can't tell what dependancies are already installed. I could be worried over nothing . . . but I'd wait for a wiser brain than mine to comment.

Answer (score 0):

### To install/reinstall the Ubuntu Update Manager ("Software Updater")

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install update-manager
```

You'll now see this "**Software Updater**" icon when you press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and then search for "updater":

[image]

And this .desktop file will now be created: "**/usr/share/applications/update-manager.desktop**", and it will contain the following, as shown by `cat /usr/share/applications/update-manager.desktop`:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Software Updater
GenericName=Software Updates
Comment=Show and install available updates
Exec=/usr/bin/update-manager
Icon=system-software-update
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=System;Settings;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=update-manager
X-Unity-IconBackgroundColor=#4c9e39
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Ubuntu 20.04** for me helped the following:

`sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`

In the start of the config add link to the repository with focal-updates:

`deb https://mirror.linux-ia64.org/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse`

If this server is not working try another servers that listed here: [Official Archive Mirrors for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install update-manager`

Source: [Trying to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` causes dependency issues (Ubuntu GNOME, 18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195601/trying-to-reinstall-ubuntu-desktop-causes-dependency-issues-ubuntu-gnome-18)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps (re-installing the packages):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-update-manager python3-apt python3-gi update-manager python3-dbus python3-aptdaemon aptdaemon lsb-release python3-defer python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-dbus
```