# how to start update process in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: updates

I cant find how to start updating process in "software and updates" in system setting, I only can find 2 Buttons close and revert

Comment: is `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` working ??

Comment: yes, but i want to know why i cant do it thro software and updates , and is it the same ?

Comment: here is a similar question http://askubuntu.com/questions/546363/software-updater-software-updates-not-working-on-14-04-lts

Comment: if these solution not working reinstall it http://askubuntu.com/questions/307441/how-to-install-again-update-manager-after-uninstalling-it

Answer (score 1):

The Software and Update in System settings is for specifying which repositories is to used during use during update.The actual Gui tool used for updating is software updater .It can be accessed by typing software updater or update manager in the dash by pressing super key.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press the Super Key (usually has a Windows logo on it) to open the
   dash.
2. Type "Software Updater".
3. Click the first result.

Comment: i didnt ask where it's , iam saying when i goto system setting and then software and update i can find list of updates but i cant start it , cos there is no start or install button