# Trying to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` causes dependency issues (Ubuntu GNOME, 18.04)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I was trying to get rid of `update-notifier` because it was being a pain, and I did `sudo apt remove update-notifier`. I didn't really look at the details but I should have; it also removed the `ubuntu-desktop` package with it. It didn't crash my current instance or whatever.

So I tried installing it back, with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`, but this causes a dependecy hell:

When I try to install `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: update-manager but it is not going to be installed
```

When I do `sudo apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-manager`:

```
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (= 1:18.04.17) but 1:18.04.34 is to be installed
                               Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:18.04.17) but 1:18.04.34 is to be installed
 update-manager : Depends: update-manager-core (= 1:18.04.11) but 1:18.04.11.10 is to be installed
```

These above packages are already installed on my system. Yes, I have done `sudo apt update`.

What do I do to get it back?

Comment: I would check your sources and your chosen mirror, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ubuntu-release-upgrader-core shows your ubuntu-release-upgrade-gtk is *out-of-date* like you haven't `sudo apt update` yet (which you say you have; thus the mirror check).   Do you get any errors in your `sudo apt update`, are all expected lines there?, and from what mirror?   Check on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors to see if it's *up-to-date* is my first suggestion.

Comment: @guiverc I just added a new "Up to date" repo to sources.list, and it still doesn't work. Still shows this incompatiblity hell.

Comment: Oh yes! Turns out the issue is with the `bionic` channel having an outdated version. Adding `bionic-updates` to my sources.list fixed it.