# How to disable the update manager and notifier safely in 15.10?

Tags: updates, 15.10

I do `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` manually almost every day and I am happy doing it manually. I don't need the Ubuntu update manager and want not to be annoyed by it ever. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/218792/2390) suggests it can be removed but it seems that the things have changed since it was written as now

```
sudo apt-get remove update-manager
```

as well as

```
sudo apt-get remove update-notifier
```

result in

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop* ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk* update-manager* update-notifier*
```

response. Needless to say I don't want to remove the whole Ubuntu Desktop.

So what is the correct way?

Answer (score 4):

Um, open `software and updates`, choose the `updates` tab, and change `Automatically check for updates` to `never`?

To stop the notifications themselves, start `dconf-editor`

Navigate to com->ubuntu->undate-notifier and check the box for 'no-show-notifications'

Or execute

`gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier no-show-notifications true`

Comment: It doesn't really help as it still becomes aware of the updates available as soon as I run `apt-get update` for some reason. And, on occasion (I am not sure but it feels like) even if I don't.

Comment: It will at least stop it from looking by itself, or should.  The notifier is a little more of an issue, which I would also like to resolve.

Comment: @Ivan Adding some more information...