# Why do I no longer get informed that updates are available by a pop up?

Tags: 16.04, updates

I am using 16.04LTS.Until recently I quite often got informed by a popup in the same place as the wifi connected/disconnected information appears, that 'Important OS and application updates are ready..."

I usually checked with the new 'Ubuntu Software' icon which informed me that certain updates were available. The popup and Ubuntu Software appeared to be in sync. I've noticed recently that I never seem to get the popup anymore. Today I changed the options under System Settings/Software & Updates/Updates to display all available updates immediately.

I shut down and restarted, yet no popup appears, despite there being a new kernel available according to 'Ubuntu Software'/Updates.

Can anyone  please tell me the cause and hopefully a solution for this new problem?

***Update***

Today both 'Ubuntu Software' and 'Software Updater' tell me that updates are available, yet I still get no popup. Googling a bit led me to look in **/var/lib/update-notifier** where I see a file named **updates-available** dated an hour ago.
Its contents (text) are:

**6 packages can be updated**

**6 updates are security updates**

Perhaps this is useful information for anyone who might be able to assist me.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/218755/how-to-disable-the-update-manager-popup

Comment: Why don't you set-up a script that runs the updates automatically every time you login, in the background, without noticing? That way your system is always up to date. If interested, can provide the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the **dconf-editor** and checking if *no-show-notifications* is set to true, so you can set it to false, once open you'll find this boolean flag in ***com > ubuntu > update-notifier***

[image]

To install the **dconf-editor**:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

To access other relevant **update-notifier** options via terminal:

```
update-notifier --help
```

Comment: This was a reasonable long shot but that field was already set to 'false'.

Comment: The issue is likely with the notify-osd Ubuntu notification API, it looks like one of the few options is installing a patch, read the accepted answer to this other question:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications#128508

There is another link of interest on the same website about Ubuntu 16.04 specifically: 

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/05/customize-notifyosd-notification.html