# How to disable periodic "Application Apply Full Upgrade Has Closed Unexpectedly"

Tags: upgrade, updates, crash

I have been periodically (maybe daily?) been getting this error message since I virtualized my Ubuntu 22.04 partition.

[image]

I don't want to re-launch the application (so I have to take special care to uncheck this every time), I don't know why it's even trying to do a full upgrade without my permission, and I would like to disable it from making this attempt!  If I ignore the dialog another one pops up on top of it in another day or so, so this doesn't prevent it from running again either.

When I go to "Software and Updates" it says (under the "Updates" tab) that I am "subscribed" to "Security Updates Only" but does not provide any way to subscribe to less than that.  It is already set to automatically check for updates "Never".  I also changed "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" to "Never" but a day or two later and this crash report pops up again!

Update:
Here is the output of the commands requested in the comments.

```
$ grep "Prompt" /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
Prompt=never
$ do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
In /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades Prompt 
is set to never so upgrading is not possible.
$ dpkg -s unattended-upgrades | grep "Status"
Status: install ok installed
```

Update: Here is some of the output of the file left in /var/crash:

```
ProblemType: Crash
CurrentDesktop: LXQt
ExecutablePath: /usr/libexec/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-notifier.py
InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.10
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/libexec/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-notifier.py -u 168 -s 166 -p /usr/bin/lubuntu-upgrader

Traceback:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/libexec/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-notifier.py", line 266, in <module>
     main(sys.argv, int(options.upgrades), int(options.security_upgrades),
   File "/usr/libexec/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-notifier.py", line 231, in main
     app = App(upgrades, security_upgrades, reboot_required, upg_path, args)
   File "/usr/libexec/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-notifier.py", line 223, in __init__
     self.dialog = Dialog(upgrades, security_upgrades, reboot_required,
   File "/usr/libexec/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-notifier.py", line 59, in __init__
     self.initUI()
   File "/usr/libexec/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-notifier.py", line 132, in initUI
     td_child = QTreeWidgetItem(p.name)
 TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
   QTreeWidgetItem(type: int = QTreeWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
   QTreeWidgetItem(Iterable[str], type: int = QTreeWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
   QTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidget, type: int = QTreeWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
   QTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidget, Iterable[str], type: int = QTreeWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
   QTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, type: int = QTreeWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
   QTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem, type: int = QTreeWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
   QTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem, Iterable[str], type: int = QTreeWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
   QTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem, QTreeWidgetItem, type: int = QTreeWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
   QTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
UserGroups: adm cdrom dip lpadmin lxd plugdev sambashare sudo
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `grep "Prompt" /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`, `do-release-upgrade -c`, and `dpkg -s unattended-upgrades | grep "Status"` to your question?

Comment: @DynamicBits Thanks, I have added that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the unattended-upgrades package is the root cause of that error message. You can disable unattended-upgrades a few different ways, while still allowing for manual updates when you are ready. Any one of the following methods should do the trick:

### **1. Change unattended-upgrades Configuration**

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

Change the 1 to 0 for each option (*APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists* and *APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade*)

### **2. Stop and Disable unattended-upgrades Service**

```
sudo systemctl stop unattended-upgrades
sudo systemctl disable unattended-upgrades
```

Verify the service is no longer running with:

```
systemctl status unattended-upgrades | grep "Active"
```

### **3. Uninstall unattended-upgrades Package**

```
sudo apt remove unattended-upgrades
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried #1 but strangely both were already set to 0.  However when I tried the second it showed that it was active and I was able to change that to say "inactive (dead)" with the systemctl commands.  I will wait a day or so to verify that the error doesn't pop up again and hold the uninstall in reserve as the big hammer just in case.

Comment: By any chance are you running a different flavor than Ubuntu, like Lubuntu?

Comment: I have installed some Lubuntu packages on top of Ubuntu - my understanding from previous feedback in a different question/answer was that it's still Ubuntu (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS as reported by lsb_release -a)

Comment: I believe all flavors of Ubuntu will show the same output. Lubuntu does have an updater of its own. What's the output of `dpkg -s lubuntu-upgrader`?

Comment: `dpkg-query: package 'lubuntu-upgrader' is not installed and no information is available`

Comment: I can't think of any other obvious sources for the error message, so I'm hoping the problem is solved. If you do get another crash report, please click "Show Details" and add that info to your question.

Comment: After the first 24 hours nothing but after 48 hours it popped up again. I'm going to try #3.

Comment: The dialog popped up again after uninstalling.  Should I need to reboot for any of this to take effect? I'm trying that next...

Comment: oh, sorry i just now again saw you asked for "Show Details" right after I dismissed the dialog... any way to get the info from a file?

Comment: I don't think a reboot will make any difference. There must be something else trying to start an update. The crash dumps are stored in */var/crash*. Just use `head` on the dump to share enough info for us to hopefully find what's causing this.

Comment: Thanks, I have added that info... it's calling a Python script with "lubuntu" in the name, that seems a pretty big clue?

Comment: I found this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1404298/82144

Comment: Oh, boy.. I had the wrong package name earlier. If `dpkg -s lubuntu-update-notifier` shows that it is installed, `sudo apt remove lubuntu-update-notifier` should do the trick.

Comment: hmm, welll... `sudo apt remove lubuntu-update-notifier` also says it is going to remove `lubuntu-desktop` which seems like might be bad since i'm running lxqt?

Comment: hmm, maybe not... https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/lubuntu-desktop/filelist.  Only two text files?  What's the purpose of this package anyway...

Comment: It is a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages). `apt-cache show lubuntu-desktop` will show you the depends. The end of that will say *It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades, but it can be safely removed if you want to remove some applications installed by default.* Since you installed Lubuntu packages on top of Ubuntu, it's not very clear to me exactly what you have installed. You may have other issues when you update to a new release. But you should be able to fix the notifier issue today and worry about that when it comes time to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed that package and hopefully will not see any more popups in the next day or two!

Comment: It seems to be fixed, thanks!