# Ubuntu air-gapped system "the update information is outdated." -- Do NOT want to update, ever

Tags: apt, 22.04

I have air gapped systems with Ubuntu 22.04 desktop.  I get a red circle exclamation point.  If I click, I get "the update information is outdated.  This may be caused network problems or ..."

The problem is that these computers should **never** be connected to the Internet and updated.  Using a mirror also isn't an option.  Using apt-offline isn't an option.  The computer is supposed to remain isolated -- no network, no USB but does have a KB, mouse and RS-232 serial to a lab device.

My research has only found solutions that involve connecting to the Internet, disabling repos no longer available, fixing broken packages, etc.  None of those fit the problem.

I also tried seeing if the message could be disabled from its own menu.  After clicking the icon, I selected preferences.  This results in the program crashing.  That temporarily gets rid of the annoying icon but it will return in a few days.

**What I want is for the alert/message to go away and never come back.**

Comment: Try finding the path to the executable that is crashing, finding the package that provides it, then uninstalling that package?

Comment: Did you disable or set the `Automatically check for updates:` to `Never` in the Software & Updates -> Updates tab in settings?  Have you checked all of the software preferences to not have Automatic Updates enabled like in GNOME Software?

Comment: Why is it not suitable to just remove all referecnces to all respositories in your `sources.list` and `sources.list.d/*.list` files, as you imply. Surely this is precisely the right way to disable all updates, by disabling all repos.

Comment: Thanks Terrance.  Was already set to Never.  I'm not aware of every other place to check. | Thanks popey.  I had already tried that too.

Comment: See my simple answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1503093/1004020